# How to hide a widget with pyuic5

Tags: python, pyuic

Is there a way to hide a widget(in pyuic5).
I've tried:

```
self.playBtn.hide()
```

which doesn't cause an error, but doesn't hide the widget. That was kind of a shot in the dark, and the documentation isn't providing too much info. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a solid color background:

- you can draw or create a sprite that is the same color of the background and position it on top of the button

Or

- you can delete the element and re-create it when you want to show it